# Need Some Active Directory Suggestions

Tags: active-directory, activedirectorymembership, active-directory-group

First off, I'm a newbie at AD; I know how to setup a basic domain, but that's it.

I'm running a hosting service for some Windows Applications.  User permissions is based on Active Directory security groups.

Let's say I have `Contoso.local` as my Forest - the NetBIOS name is `CONTOSO`.  I want to provide a SaaS where clients can sync their Active Directory users and/or groups to my AD while keeping their own NetBIOS name.  For example, if I had a client who somewhere on the globe was named Acme and their forest domain was `Acme.local` and their NetBIOS name was `ACME`, then I would want John Doe to have the ability of logging into my SaaS as `ACME\John.Doe` instead of me having to manage all users for my clients and requiring John to login as `CONTOSO\John.Doe`.  The idea here is white labeling.

Immediately, you're probably thinking **AD FS**, but my SaaS doesn't support Federated Services.

I could set up another domain controller on my network to replicate against my client, but that seems overkill.  And, I don't know how to accomplish this.

Is there no way for my AD to simply sync and/or authenticate against another domain's users and groups?  (I need groups too, because depending on the security role, a user has access to specific info.)  Can I setup a Trust or LDS to accomplish this?

If so, or if not, please provide suggestions.  Some how-to's would also be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Joshua

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understood exactly what it is you are trying to do, but yes, Federation might have been an answer. Apart from federation, I suppose using forest trusts might be one way to accomplish the objective of letting users log in with their native domain\account names. Just an idea.